# How to find the users/roles running highest number of queries

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to find the users and corresponding no.of queries executed by the user   for all users  in  snowflake account.

I like to see output some thing like this for all the users.

username    no.of queries executed by user

XXXXXXX      50

The below query helps in getting the details of queries executed by single user.

```
select query_text,
       warehouse_name,
       database_name,
       schema_name,
       user_name,
       role_name,
       execution_status,
       error_code,
       error_message,
       start_time,
       end_time
from table(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER('USERNAME')) -- put username here
order by start_time desc;
```

Let me know for nay details required.

Comment: i just got this to know the count    SELECT query_history.USER_NAME  AS "query_history.user_name",
count( query_history.QUERY_TEXT)  AS "query_history.count" 
      FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY  AS query_history where
       query_history.query_text like '%select%'
      group by query_history.USER_NAME order by count( query_history.QUERY_TEXT) desc  ;                                                                                                                                                                                     is their any other better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Query_history view in the  account_usage schema though there will be a little delay in propagating the latest details. You can group by the user_name column.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view